# Deducting the median from each column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe, `df` with numbers, like so:

```
1 1 1
2 1 1
2 1 3
```

I'd like to deduct the median from each column so that the median of each becomes 0.

```
-1 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 2
```

How do I do this in a pythandic way? I'm guessing it is possible without iterating over the values, computing the median and then deducting. I'd like to do it tersely, approximately like so:

```
from numpy import median
df -= median(df) #does not work, deducts median for whole dataframe
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like this

```
df -= df.median(axis=0)
```

`median` of `numpy` computes **median** of overall data.
To accomplish using `numpy`, try this code instead.

```
df -= median(df, axis=0)
```

for more detail, see the document: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html

Comment: Does this really subtract the median of each column? Seems it would do the overall median.

Answer (score 1):

Some testing in ipython showed:

```
In [23]: A = numpy.arange(9)

In [24]: B = A.reshape((3,3))

In [25]: C = numpy.median(B,axis=0)

In [26]: D = B - C[None,:]

In [27]: B
Out[27]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [28]: D
Out[28]: 
array([[-3., -3., -3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.]])
In [29]: C
Out[29]: array([ 3.,  4.,  5.])
```

So the next line gets the median along the columns

```
C = numpy.median(B,axis=0)
```

And the next line subtracts it from the matrix, column by column

```
D = B - C[None,:]
```

Comment: In numpy 1.9 `median` has a `keepdims` keyword argument that will spare you the `None` indexing (which isn't needed in this particular case anyway).

Comment: @Jaime its a habit i guess (explicit is better than implicit?)